# upload data and save it using ASIHTTP

Tags: iphone, upload, save, asihttprequest

I have a web page in which a value 'A' is constantly updated. I use ASIHttp to access the page contents and get this value 'A'. Based on A i calculate value X and i then i need to save this X to a webpage. I am able to get the data and am doing the calculation to get X. How do i upload and save the X to a webpage using ASIHTTP so that the X value can be used later.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [sample code](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) sections of `ASIHTTPRequest` to learn how to use [`ASIFormDataRequest`](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIFormDataRequest.h) to easily submit a POST request to your web service.